# jQuery .animate() forces style "overflow:hidden"

Tags: jquery, css

jQuery's `.animate()` forces the style `overflow: hidden` when triggered, messing with my animated element because I have another element that's hanging, with negative position, outside of it. is there anyway to avoid that?

Comment: you can use $('element').animate().css('overflow', 'visible'); for some testing, can you post some code?

Comment: This works, because .animate() sets the overflow only once when it starts! thanks =)

Comment: holy crap i just spent about four hours trying to work around this issue.  yes!!!

Comment: @tkone I know that feel, bro.

Answer (score 53):

Another way is to declare the element as **!important** in css.

For example.

```
.somediv {
  overflow: visible !important;
}
```

Comment: @ScottGreenfield Not in Chrome 17.0

Comment: @ScottGreenfield - that is not correct.  ! important takes precedence over inline styles.

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#cascading-order
Author important style declarations overide normal ones, regardless of specificity, inline styles have the highest specificity, but do not take precedence over styles declared important.

Answer (score 30):

This is the source code:

```
  if ( isElement && ( p === "height" || p === "width" ) ) {
    // Make sure that nothing sneaks out
    // Record all 3 overflow attributes because IE does not
    // change the overflow attribute when overflowX and
    // overflowY are set to the same value
    opt.overflow = [ this.style.overflow, this.style.overflowX, this.style.overflowY ];
  ...
  ...
  ...
  }

if ( opt.overflow != null ) {
  this.style.overflow = "hidden";
}
```

You can comment this out if you want, or simply use `$('element').animate().css('overflow', 'visible');` as previously suggested.

The reason the overflow is set to hidden is so that elements within the one being animated will be contained within the element whilst it is being animated.  For instance, if you reduce an element's width, its contents might try to elongate and "fall" out the bottom.

This is explained in the source code above by the comment:

> // Make sure that nothing sneaks out

Hope that explains it for you.

Answer (score 11):

Any of those solutions worked for me, but I found the trick:

```
$(myDiv).animate(
   { height: newHeight},
   { duration: 500, 
     queue: false, 
     easing: 'easeOutExpo', 

     step: function() {
       $(myDiv).css("overflow","visible");
     }
   }
);
```

Force the css in each step of the animation. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 4):

When using `$('element').animate().css('overflow', 'visible');` it can cause problems if `overflow-x` and `overflow-y` are already specified for the element.

In those cases use `$('element').animate().css('overflow', '');` which just removes the overflow attribute and keeps the `overflow-x` and `overflow-y` intact.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass :

`function(e){$('#something').css('overflowY', 'scroll');}`

to the .animate() options parameter, as a function to run when animation is 'complete', like so:

```
$('#something').animate({
                    width: '100px',
                    height: '100px',
                    overflowY: 'scroll !important' //doesn't work
                }, { duration: 500, queue: false, complete: function(e){$('#something').css('overflowY', 'scroll');} } );
```

Comment: How would that help? The hiding takes place *during* the animation, not *after* it.

Comment: I gotta say this solution helped me better. It let me keep the scroll after the animation, I just added the same thing in the animation so the scroll would always be there. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

My preferred answer is to use `$.Animation.prefilter`.
[Here is a jsfiddle.net example.](http://jsfiddle.net/0skne2at/2/)

Set up the prefilter:

```
jQuery.Animation.prefilter(function(element, properties, options) {
  if (options.overrideOverflow) {
    jQuery(element).css("overflow", options.overrideOverflow);
  }
});
```

Then use it

```
$(myDiv).animate(
  { height: newHeight},
  {
    duration: 500, 
    overrideOverflow: "visible" // Replace "visible" with your desired overflow value
  }
);
```

Note that you cannot use the option name `overflow` because jQuery uses that internally.

Although this feature has been around in jQuery for a while, it seems that the documentation is not complete. But [draft documentation is available](https://gist.github.com/gnarf/54829d408993526fe475#prefilters).

Also see https://github.com/jquery/api.jquery.com/issues/256

Comment: This is a neat approach. I had not reached into the methods available on the jQuery.Animation object much. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

PERFECT "Eagle" (2 Posts Up).  If I didn't run across your reply I would have been searching for hours for this I bet.

"Eagle" Posted the correct way to go about this.

All the other solutions are just hacks. This was the correct way (reiterating), that is why they give you all the options when using the "animate" class.

Below are some of the settings available (from the documentation, https://api.jquery.com/animate/). I needed the "complete" setting to perform an action when the animation was finished.

```
    duration (default: 400)
    easing (default: swing)
    queue (default: true)
    specialEasing
    step
    progress
    complete
    start
    done
    fail
    always
```

This is going to make working with animations much easier and I will be using this format whether or not it is needed, for all animations in the future.

Comment: That is not an answer. Post it as comment! 
However the answer you mentioned is the greatest hack in my eyes. 
You add overflow:visible in every step of the animation which is completely not needed because you only have to set in once. 

Furtermore jquery is removing the overflow:hidden itself when the animation is finished so you don't have to do that yourself.