# jQuery Animate - doesn't animate absolute DIV

Tags: jquery, animation, css-position

do you know why i cant animate a absolute-positioning div with jQuery?

show please here (here is my example ):

http://jsfiddle.net/2VJe8/

HTML:

```
<html>
<body>
    <div class="test">
        <div class="box">
            <div class="arrow"></div> 
        </div>
        <a href="#" class="btnStartAni">Animate</a>
    </div>
</body>
```

​

CSS:

```
.test { margin: 0; padding: 0;}
.test .box { width: 150px; height: 140px; background-color: red; position: relative; }
.test .box .arrow { width: 50px; height: 50px; background-color: black; position: 
absolute; bottom: 0; right: -50px;}​
```

JavaScript:

```
jQuery(".test a.btnStartAni").on("click", function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
  jQuery(".box").animate({ width: 400}, 800);
});
```

​

the black box is during animation hide! But i dont know why?

can you help me please?

Comment: jQuery adds `overflow:hidden` during the animation. Not sure why.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

jQuery causes the overflow to be hidden when you use `.animate`, so change your code to

```
jQuery(".test a.btnStartAni").on("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    jQuery(".box").animate({ width: 400}, 800).css('overflow', 'visible');
});
​
```

And it should work

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2VJe8/1/

Source: [jQuery .animate() forces style "overflow:hidden"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3363035/jquery-animate-forces-style-overflowhidden)

Comment: An alternate (preferred) solution is to set `overflow: visible !important;` to `.box` in the CSS.

Answer (score 2):

`overflow: hidden` gets set on `.box` when jQuery animates the box. `.arrow` overflows from `.box` and so disappears. Consider changing the markup.

Answer (score 1):

You can also re-arrange the elements to get the same effect (using `float:left` and `display:inline-block`)

http://jsfiddle.net/mkVrL/