# hide div hidden:overflow issue

Tags: jquery, html, user-interface

I have 2 divs a & b as well as an close and open button (open is not displayed until click close).  When I click close div a is hidden and the width of div b is animated to 100%.  This works as expected until I add `html,body{height:100%}` which I need in order for everything to take up 100% of available browser height. When I click close div b "flashes" because jQuery animate is adding `overflow:hidden` to it.  If I add `overflow:visible !important` to the element it removes the flash but doesn't animate the way that I want (remove `height:100%` from `#content` div to see desired result).  How can I get my animation to not do the flash and still achieve the desired result?

HTML

```
    <div id="content" style="height:100%">
    <div id="openBtn" style="background:aquamarine;display:none;top:0;position:absolute;left:0">Open</div>
    <div id="titleVidNavContainer" style="float:left;width:20%;position:relative;height:100%">
        <div id="videoTitleNav" style="min-height:100%; height:500px;background:purple;white-space: nowrap;">&nbsp;</div>       
        <div id="hideBtn" style="background:aquamarine; position:absolute;top:0;right:-35px;display:inline-block">Close</div>
    </div>
    <div id="videoContent" style="background:aqua;height:500px;width:80%;float:left;height:100%">&nbsp;</div>       
</div>
```

CSS

```
html,body{height:100%}
```

jQuery

```
         $("#hideBtn").click(function () {
            $(this).hide("slide", { direction: 'left' }, 200);
            setTimeout(function() {
                $("#titleVidNavContainer").animate({ width: '0' });
                $("#videoContent").animate({ width: '100%' }).css({ 'float': 'none' });
                $("#openBtn").show("slide", { direction: 'left' }, 500);
            },300);
        });

        $("#openBtn").click(function () {
            $(this).hide();
            $("#titleVidNavContainer").animate({ width: '20%' },400);
            setTimeout(function() { $("#hideBtn").show("slide", { direction: 'left' }, 200); },500);
            //setTimeout(function() { $("#videoContent").animate({ width: '80%' }).css('float', 'left'); },1000);
            $("#videoContent").css('float', 'left').animate({ width: '80%' });
        });
```

**EDIT:** I originally choose not to inlcude the jsFiddle for this, because it wasn't replicating the problem as the way I see it.  No matter it might help -  [jsfiddle.net/comatoseduck/KstHH](http://www.jsfiddle.net/comatoseduck/KstHH)

**EDIT 2:** This is as close to a fix as I have gotten so far, though it still doesn't give me the desired result - [jQuery .animate() forces style “overflow:hidden”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3363035/jquery-animate-forces-style-overflowhidden)

Comment: You will get better results if you show it live on jsfiddle.net

Comment: I do have a fiddle for this, it's just not replicating the problem the way I see it so I chose not to include it...but if you think it would help http://jsfiddle.net/comatoseduck/KstHH/

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
html,body{margin: 0; padding: 0;}
```

instead of

```
html,body{height:100%}
```

Comment: Might as well keep the `margin: 0px;` ;)

Comment: Sure this fixes my problem with the "flash", but div a & b are no longer taking up the height of the entire available area :/

Comment: Style them accordingly. Open a new question with code and a demo if you need help.

Comment: Why would I open a new question when I stated that the requirements of this issue were for the height of div a & b be 100% of available browser height?