# My tab disappears when using jquery animate

Tags: jquery

I'm making a full height menu that'll slide out from the right hand side of the screen when you click the tab.

You'll notice that when you click the openerthingie (tab), it disappears until the animation is done and then reappears.

Why is that? And how can I get it to slide with its container?

HTML:

```
<div id="rightwrapper" class="closed">
    <div id="openertabthingie">=</div>
</div>

<div id="leftwrapper" class="closed">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#rightwrapper { position: relative; width: 0; height: 100%; float: right; background: #222; }
#rightwrapper #openertabthingie { position: absolute; height: 60px; width: 74px; top: 145px; left: -74px; background: #111; cursor: pointer; z-index: 1000; }
#leftwrapper { height: 100%; overflow: auto; position: fixed; width: 100%; background: #ccc;     }
```

And all the jquery is here to fiddle with:
http://jsfiddle.net/9k578/

[image: an example of the tab when the menu is closed (will slide to left when clicked)]

Comment: I appreciate you adding a fiddle. I'd like to help but need to know conceptually what you want to accomplish. Should this be one box animating open or closed?

Comment: my bad. basically there's a little menu that will be sliding out (open) from the right side when you click on the tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short and sweet of it is that jQuery's [animate](https://api.jquery.com/animate/) function forces an `overflow: hidden` element style for certain situations (see [jQuery .animate() forces style "overflow:hidden"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3363035/jquery-animate-forces-style-overflowhidden)).

You can add `overflow: visible` to the CSS in all the relevant places, e.g.:

```
$('#rightwrapper').animate({
    width: "+=250",
    overflow: 'visible' // ADDED CODE
}
```

### Further Explanation

See Nick's answer in the link above for further explanation:

> The reason the overflow is set to hidden is so that elements within the one being animated will be contained within the element whilst it is being animated. For instance, if you reduce an element's width, its contents might try to elongate and "fall" out the bottom.

There's a note in the jQuery [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/animate/) about overflow and height/width. So make sure you fully test the code in various screen widths, div widths, etc. =)

Comment: This didn't work for me. I added the solution that worked for me to the SO question you linked to though.