# How to prevent this H2-tag from half disappearing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I recently tried to make a smooth front page. You may see what I did in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zk755cr9/5/).

If you click on it, it will open by unfolding. But whenever the animation comes, the `<h2>` tag with `BUSINESS PC` in it disappears, where it is not covered by `<section>`.

**How can I prevent it from doing that?**

HTML:

```
<section class="mbox mbox_closed" id="effect1_1">
         <h2>BUSINESS PC</h2>

        <div class="mbox_content" id="effect2_1">
             <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr! 
                <span>sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam</span>
            </h3>

            <p>Erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <img src="http://www.club-3d.com/tl_files/club3d/uploads/en/content/Accesories/CAC-1052/cac-1052_use_01.png" alt="Testbild">
        <!--<div class="mbox_bar"></div>-->
    </section>
```

CSS:

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans);
 body, html {
    height:100%;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    background:#5cafff;
    font-family:'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
.mbox {
    z-index: 1;
    margin: 2em;
    position:relative;
    background: #ff1a00;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #ffffff 33%, #ff1a00 100%);
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    height:200px;
    clear:both;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=90)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=90);
    -moz-opacity: 0.9;
    -khtml-opacity: 0.9;
    opacity: 0.9;
}
.mbox_closed:hover {
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    -moz-opacity: 1.0;
    -khtml-opacity: 1.0;
    opacity: 1.0;
    -moz-box-shadow:  0px 0px 12px 8px rgb(128,128,128);
    -webkit-box-shadow:  0px 0px 12px 8px rgb(128,128,128);
    box-shadow:  0px 0px 12px 8px rgb(128,128,128);
}
.mbox_active {
    z-index: 1;
    margin: 2em;
    position:relative;
    background: #ff1a00;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #ffffff 33%, #ff1a00 100%);
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    height:200px;
    clear:both;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    -moz-opacity: 1.0;
    -khtml-opacity: 1.0;
    opacity: 1.0;
}
.mbox * {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
.mbox_content {
    z-index: 2;
    float:left;
    padding: 20px;
    background: #ffffff;
    width:60%;
    height:160px;
    overflow: hidden;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
.mbox img {
    z-index:-1;
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    max-height:100%;
}
.mbox hr {
    z-index: 2;
    float:left;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    margin-top: 30px;
    border-width: 15px 0 15px 20px;
    border-color: transparent transparent transparent #ffffff;
}
.mbox_bar {
    z-index: 2;
    float:right;
    width: 30;
    height: 100%;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 10px 3px 3px;
    border-color: #ffffff #ffffff #ffffff #ffffff;
}
.mbox h2 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight:normal;
    font-size:1em;
    top:-0.7em;
    left: 0.5em;
    position:absolute;
    color:#fff;
    background:#ff1a00;
    padding:0 1em;
    border:1px solid #fff;
    border-radius:1em;
}
.mbox_content h3 {
    font-size:1.4em;
    color:#666;
    border-left:2px solid #ccc;
    padding-left: 1em;
    margin-bottom:0.5em;
}
.mbox_content h3 span {
    margin-top:0.5em;
    display:block;
    font-size:0.7em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight:normal;
}
```

JS:

```
var state = []

$(function() {

        state[1] = true;

        $( "#effect1_1" ).click(function() {

            if ( state[1] ) {
                $( "#effect1_1" ).animate({
                    height: 600
                }, 1000 );
                $( "#effect2_1" ).animate({
                    height: 560
                }, 1000 );

                $( "#effect1_1" ).removeClass( "mbox_closed" ).addClass( "mbox_active" );

            } else {
                $( "#effect1_1" ).animate({
                    height: 200
                }, 1000 );
                $( "#effect2_1" ).animate({
                    height: 160
                }, 1000 );

                $( "#effect1_1" ).removeClass( "mbox_active" ).addClass( "mbox_closed" );

            }
        state[1] = !state[1];
        });
});
```

Comment: jQuery animate is setting `overflow:hidden` during the animation. See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3363035/jquery-animate-forces-style-overflowhidden).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery `animate()` adds `overflow: hidden` by default during all animations.

A simple way to get round this is to set `overflow: visible !important;` on the element that is being animated.

In your case its the `.mbox` class.

```
.mbox {
    /* other css */
    overflow: visible !important;
}
```

[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/zk755cr9/6/)

Answer (score 4):

You will have to override `overflow: hidden;` that jQuery animate is setting on your animated elements.

```css
.mbox {
    overflow: visible !important;
}
```

Comment: This totally works! Please understand that I will mark @Stewartside 's answer, as he's been quicker for a few seconds.

Answer (score 2):

add following to css

```
#effect1_1{
overflow:visible !important;
}
```

the reason behind this is when you animate height it automatically set **overflow hidden** for the time of animation and then reset it to visible thats why it just disappears when its animating.